# BlackBerry TreeField: Setting different height for each row

Tags: blackberry, java-me, treefield

The [`TreeField.setRowHeight(int height)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html#setRowHeight%28int%29) method just sets equal height for each of the rows of the [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html), but I want to set different height for each row. Is it possible? I couldn't find any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to set different height for each row in [`TreeField`](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html), at least currently there is no documented method.

Check the answer of following question asked on *BlackBerry Developer Support Forums* -

[How to create a layout like this: TreeField with variable RowHeight](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-create-a-layout-like-this-TreeField-with-variable/m-p/346612#M64069).